# page doesn't update after i change selected option in htmlunit

Tags: java, htmlunit

i am new to htmlunit . it's going so well untill i want change lessontype in our university site . the problem is that when i change selected option the page content doesn't update and results are same . how i can solve this problem ?

```
public static void main(String [] args ) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException, InterruptedException 
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);

    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF); 
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://amozesh.araku.ac.ir");
    HtmlTextInput name = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("UserCode");
    HtmlPasswordInput pass = (HtmlPasswordInput)page.getElementByName("KeyCode");
    HtmlElement submitButton = (HtmlElement) page.getElementById("input");
    name.setText(user);
    pass.setText(passs);

    System.out.println(page.getTitleText());
    HtmlPage pagePassVarified = submitButton.click();
    System.out.println(pagePassVarified.getTitleText());
    //successfully login

    final HtmlPage page2 = webClient.getPage("http://amozesh.araku.ac.ir/LessonReport.asp");

    HtmlSelect select = (HtmlSelect) page2.getElementByName("LessonType");
    System.out.println(page2.asText()); // i get content before changing selected option
    System.out.println(select.getDefaultValue());

    // changing selected option 
    HtmlOption option = select.getOptionByValue("1");
    select.setSelectedAttribute(option, true);

    //i get below section from other's post that have problem like me but      doesn't work for me
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController()); 
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    synchronized (page2) 
    {
        System.out.println("wait");
        page2.wait(500);
    }


    System.out.println(page2.asText()); //i get content after changing selected option but it still same ):
    System.out.println(select.getDefaultValue());// selected value is changed!



}
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to post read-only username and password?

Comment: no , sorry. please help me.

Comment: Then, ensure you use latest version (or better snapshot), then check why the 'change' JavaScript handler of HtmlSelect/HtmlOption do not work, please read http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html

Comment: how i can send you my user and pass to check out my problem?

Comment: ok ,so give me your email address.

Comment: Please read my previous comment, or [here](https://sourceforge.net/u/asashour/profile/)